# Magento print transcational emali before mail send

Tags: magento-1.7

is it possible to print transaction email body before email send? I just want to see how to display layout after display value in transactional email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Magento emails are send through this method: `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send()`.
Here is how I usually check my e-mail templates. In the method mentioned above, right after these lines:

```
if($this->isPlain()) {
    $mail->setBodyText($text);
} else {
    $mail->setBodyHTML($text);
}
```

I add this:

```
echo $text;exit;
```

instead of sending an e-mail it just prints it in the browser.
Don't forget to remove this line after you're done testing.
If you want to use the this in a live environment and save all the send e-mails you will have to do a more elaborate thing, live overriding the class, and not stopping the script at all, but you can do all this in the same place.

Comment: Thank you very much. i tested it and its working. Sorry for late as i was busy in my magento work. Thanks for quick reply.